# Как оптимизировать загрузку изображений?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Имеется страница с большим количеством текста и картинок, грузится ужасно долго и жрет кучу траффика. Есть смысл может написать какой-то скрипт, который будет превьюшки возвращать вместо целого изображения? Я так понимаю, если контейнер 100х100, а картинка 3000х3000, то она всё равно грузится целиком? Может есть для этого какие-то стандартные решения, чтобы не изобретать колесо?
В идеале хотелось бы, чтобы грузилось под размер контейнера автоматом (в данном примере 100х100), а при клике грузился полный размер, при повторном клике сворачивалось назад...

Comment: Если есть nginx - можно юзать https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html#image_filter он будет генерировать картинки нужных размеров на лету и кешировать их.

Comment: Ну у меня настолько серьезно перегруженных проектов, как платформы, где он внедрялся, нет, а для просто поиграться и в образовательных целях приобретать платного монстра не планировалось. Но делает он то, что хотелось бы. Только бы по проще, без лишних наворотов, и чтобы работало на халявных хостингах

Answer (score 0):

Картинки можно обрезать на php
+

как вариант можно в атрибут **src** вставлять обрезаную картинку 100*100

Дальше добавить ко всем тегам img какой нибудь дата атрибут(data-image-origin) в который записывать пук к оригинальной картинке. На js при клике на картинку подменять значение атрибута src на значение data-image-origin